# In .Net how can you tell what format the clipboard was set to

Tags: .net, clipboard

The Clipboard object has a ContainsData() method that can tell if a specific format can be retrieved, but is there any way to tell what format was used to set that data in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.getdataobject.aspx) to get an [IDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.idataobject_members.aspx) instance, then call [GetFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557793.aspx) on that to get a list of the supported formats.